# how to loop through object property's created by Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, object, foreach, for-in-loop, defineproperty

i have the following object in my program

```
function Player(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.healthid = this.id + "health";
    this.displayText = "blah blah";
    this.inFight = false;
    this.currentLocation = 0;
    this.xp = 0;
    this.level = 1;
}

var player = new Player('player');

player.currentHealth = player.health;
```

and i print out the property names like so

```
function displayStats() {
    var statsHtml = "";
    for ( var prop in player ) {
        statsHtml += "<p id = 'displayPlayerHealth'>" + prop + "</p>";
    }

    $('.stats').html( statsHtml);
    console.log(statsHtml);
}

displayStats();
```

which works fine, however the other property's which i declare like so

```
Object.defineProperty(player,"health",{ 
    set: function() { 
    return 10 + ( this.level * 15 );
    }, 
    get: function() { 
    return 10 + ( this.level * 15 );
    } 
} );


Object.defineProperty(player,"strength",{ 
    set: function() { 
        return ( this.level * 5 );
    }, 
    get: function() { 
        return ( this.level * 5 );
    } 
} );

Object.defineProperty(player,"hitRating",{ 
    set: function() { 
        return 3 + ( this.level );
    }, 
    get: function() { 
        return 3 + ( this.level );
    } 
} );
```

dont print out [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8jpCM/1/).

now i put in this code to make sure they are defined

```
console.log(player.hitRating);
```

which gives me `4`, exactly what i expect.

so how do i loop through the property's of a object which were created with `Object.defineProperty`?

any other comments and help on my code are also appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make them `enumerable: true`

```
Object.defineProperty(player,"hitRating",{ 
    set: function() { 
        return 3 + ( this.level );
    }, 
    get: function() { 
        return 3 + ( this.level );
    },
    enumerable: true 
} );
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8jpCM/2/)

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

> *enumerable*
>   true if and only if this property shows up during
>   enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object. **Defaults
>   to false**.

Comment: and how do you make members (functions, this variables, etc), not defined by `Object.defineProperty` NOT enumerable? Any way to do that?